# Print the first paragraph of the first occurence in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have 2 para(eg)

```
<name>abcd</name><value>efgh</value>
<name>hijk</name><value>lmno</value>

<name>kjhg</name><value>abcd</value>
<name>jjjj</name><value>llll</value>
```

I want to search if `a` is present in the paragraph(the first occurence) and print the entire paragraph.
My output should be as below:

```
<name>abcd</name><value>efgh</value>
```

Comment: one single line is not obligatory a paragraph. A paragraph can occupy few lines. If it's about html paragraph - you should rely on `<p>` tag, if it's about one single line - note, that someone can break the line with `<br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk in "paragraph mode", by unsetting the record separator `RS`:

```
awk -v RS= '/a/ { print; exit }' file
```

When the paragraph matches the regular expression `/a/`, awk prints and exits.

Answer (score 0):

use grep:

```
grep "<name>.*a.*</name>" file
```

this will output all lines from file, where there is 'a' in name tag. dot (.) - means any character. A regular expression followed by an asterisk (*) matches zero or more occurrences of the regular expression. If there is any choice, the first matching string in a line is used.

Comment: I want to print the entire paragraph